# PHP: If more than one name

Tags: php

Im making a PM system.

In the recipient field, if you enter

```
Fox
```

It will return: Did you mean Megan Fox?

But what if there is more than Megan, having lastname "Fox", then it will only ask if you meant only one of them.

If there's more than 1 with lastname "Fox" then i wish it to say:

```
Who did you mean?
Pammy Fox
Megan Fox
```

And if there only is 1 with that lastname, i wish it to just say

```
Did you mean Megan Fox?
```

(like it does now)

How can i do that?

here's my code:

```
$qur = mysql_query("
 SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
 (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname = '$lastname') AS full FROM users 
 WHERE (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') 
 OR (firstname LIKE '$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '$lastname%')
 OR firstname LIKE '$firstname%' OR lastname LIKE '$firstname%'
 ORDER BY (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') DESC");

 $get = mysql_fetch_array($qur);

 if($get["full"] == 1){
 echo $get["id"];
 }else{
 echo "Did you mean: ".$get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"]." ?";
 }
```

Comment: As this has been flagged as a duplicate, you might want to explicitly point out how it's different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105603/php-if-no-first-name).  It took me a few minutes to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   while($get = mysql_fetch_array($qur)) {
       $name[] = $get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"];
   }

   if(count($name) > 1) {
       echo 'Who did you mean?<br/>';
   } else {
       echo 'Did you mean ';
   }
   echo implode('<br/>', $name);
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer. Great example.

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_num_rows($result)`

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($get = mysql_fetch_array($qur) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

I think anyway, been a long time since I've used mysql with PHP